# Do fat people have more chances of developing nitrogen bends?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, blood-circulation, respiration, circulatory-system

I was reading some text on deep sea physiology. I got to know that solubility of nitrogen in fat is five times that in water. The exact text from the book **animal physiology adaptation and environment** by Knut Schmidt-Nielsen, was:-

> The body fat, which in a normal lean male constitutes about 15% of body weight, dissolves about five times as much nitrogen per unit weight as does water

I think that having more body fat increases your body's nitrogen saturation capacity, thereby increasing the probability of nitrogen bends.
(Nitrogen bends or aeroembolism is the phenomenon in which nitrogen gas forms bubbles in the blood stream near joints and cause pain)

So can I conclude that fat people (those who have more body fat), are more likely to develop nitrogen bends in their blood stream?

I'd be grateful if anyone out there can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're right! First of all,

> Nitrogen Bends or **Decompression sickness** (DCS) is a disease that arises as a **consequence
>   of bubbles** forming within tissues. Inert gases, such as **nitrogen**
>   and **helium**, **enter the body through the lungs** during inspiration.
>
> **Increased BMI** (Body Mass Index) implies an **increased fat content** of the body. This
>   increased body fat **leads to increased nitrogen storage** and hence
>   possible **excessive nitrogen bubble** formation and thus increased the
>   *risk of development of DCS.*

Learn more about the relation between **Fat and Nitrogen Bends** by reading **[Diving and Hyperbaric Medicine  Volume 36 No. 3 September 2006](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/54e2/518276637fe0b71693facc3d60ccbabf2bd0.pdf)**

Comment: Your Welcome, @Anonymous! Please read the link I've attached. It will surely answer your question with some more clarity.